# FQDN for Azure VNG dynamic IP

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network

I'm aware that Azure does not support static IP address on their VNG. Is it possible in anyway to configure FQDN for the VNG in such a way that when the IP address changes due to a restart, connection would still me maintained as long as DNS record is mapped to the new IP. I will appreciate 3rd party suggestion from Azure marketplace

Comment: Any more updates on the question? Does it solve your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, yes. You can create an alias record set for the public IP with the type Azure resource in the DNS Zone. Then the DNS Zone will route your requests to that public IP, no matter if the IP address changes.

By the way, when you use the VPN, you install the client and connect the Azure VNet from your local network, in this step, you do not care about the public IP of the VPN. So I don't think you need to configure the FQDN for the public IP of the VPN. Of course, maybe you have a special reason. This just is advice.

Comment: Thank you Xu for your recommendation.